# Redirection in a Facebook Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Currently I use the following in the ASP.net C# code behind of my IFrame Facebook application:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I heard of using

```
<fb:redirect url=\""/>
```

but if this is the correct way, how would I use it to navigate between pages in the root level of my ASP.net project?  Please provide examples because I learn best from them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `fb:redirect` tag works for FBML applications, but it won't do anything in your IFrame app since `<fb:redirect />` means nothing to the browser.

The trick with IFrame apps is that if you link or redirect directly to your page, you lose all the Facebook-specific data (all the fb_sig parameters), which can break things if you don't have a way of persisting them.

I've been working on a .NET client framework for the Facebook API on CodePlex - [.NET Facebook API Client](http://facebook.codeplex.com) - which handles persisting this data for you. It's currently still in alpha, but we've got most of what I consider the more important functionality covered in our first release.